# How do I select the text on Pluma app from cursor position to the end/beginning of the current line with Shift+End/Home on laptop's keyboard?

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, cursor

The positions of my laptop's <kbd>KP_End</kbd> and <kbd>KP_Home</kbd> keys match the positions of the <kbd>1</kbd> and <kbd>7</kbd> keys of the keypad. The laptop does not have <kbd>End</kbd> or <kbd>Home</kbd> keys though. Therefore I do not know how I can select the text from the cursor position to the end/beginning of the cursor's line.

With a desktop keyboard, I do it by means of <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>/<kbd>Home</kbd>. But this laptop only has <kbd>KP_End</kbd>/<kbd>KP_Home</kbd> key. If I try <kbd>Shfit</kbd>+<kbd>KP_End</kbd>/<kbd>KP_Home</kbd> on the text editor Pluma version 1.20.1, even though the cursor does go to the end of the line, it does not select what is supposed to select. For some strange reason it does works as expected on Firefox or Abiword though.

What keyboard shortcut is there available on a laptop's keyboard to select the text from the cursor position to the end/beginning of the cursor's line working on every Ubuntu application, including Pluma?

I am on **Ubuntu 18.04** with LXDE as a desktop environment with kernel 5.4.0-050400-generic.
Thanks

Comment: I found some people already described exactly what happens to me: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1496421

Comment: The solution suggested on the following link does not work for me: https://superuser.com/questions/540221/disable-mint-cinnamon-keyboard-shortcut-shift-numpad-numlock

Answer (score 1):

By adding "numpad:microsoft", on the blank "Advance setxkbmap Options" of the keyboard layout handler, the problem got fixed. A screenshot of this blank can be found in attachment.

[image]